# Filesystem reports less available disk space than LVM (lvm with luks)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, lvm

There is this issue that has been bothering me for a while. LVM, lvdisplay, vgdisplay, pvdisplay, lsblk all shows the disk has the assigned 3.64 TB, but the filesystem is reporting it's only 1.5 TB.

I don't understand where I would need to resize, or if it's even possible?

**pvdisplay**

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-2
  VG Name               vg1
  PV Size               <3.64 TiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              953857
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          953857
  PV UUID               SAyraf-pldk-qlV2-N0op-BIGR-6HDV-TwG3O2
```

**vgdisplay**

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg1
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  10
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <3.64 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              953857
  Alloc PE / Size       953857 / <3.64 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               LCH86H-YzSJ-jCs4-tZKb-5mwz-Cedc-8FNro8
```

**lvdisplay**

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/lvol0
  LV Name                lvol0
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                6ofnPd-JNfD-wXhV-3Jny-kNAh-qu1d-TPDPJ0
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time arch, 2021-12-22 15:56:41 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <3.64 TiB
  Current LE             953857
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:4
```

**lsblk**

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sdb               8:32   0   3.6T  0 disk  
└─sdb2            8:34   0   3.6T  0 part  
  └─dm_crypt-2  254:3    0   3.6T  0 crypt 
    └─vg1-lvol0 254:4    0   3.6T  0 lvm   /mnt/bigdata
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg1-lvol0                1.5T 1020G  363G  74% /mnt/bigdata
```

How do I resize this partition to use the full 3.64 TB?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that everything is resized correctly **except** the filesystem itself.

You can resize it with `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg1-lvol0` in this case.
This was done while the disk was mounted, can't confirm if mounted or not solves the solution.